# How to make multiple minecarts turn together?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a railway and I want to have multiple carts on it. However, when I launch my carts together, the one behind jams when they come to a turn and doesn't continue. How can I make this so both carts will arrive at destination properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite simply: More spacing between your carts. Wait a little longer before firing off the second cart and the first will have cleared the corner before it gets there.

Also remember to take into account that occupied carts travel faster than unoccupied ones.

Comment: Occupied carts and unoccupied carts have the same maximum speed, so  with sufficient boost they will travel together. (Short summary: Carts have an essentially unbounded “internal” speed but their actual movement speed is capped. Unoccupied minecarts *slow down at a higher rate* than occupied minecarts.)

Comment: I'd put it more that occupied carts travel *further*. They have a higher momentum.

Comment: Thanks! works fine. I started working on a redstone circuit to delay the start of the second cart from a second rail that merges into the main one. Still working on it.